# How can I open browser from Instagram webview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, instagram

The single sign-on doesn't work on Instagram webview, I found this solution in "Mercado livre" when you open the website. But how I can do this?
[MercadoLivre inside webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9STL.png)

Instragram blocks window.location, and this another solution works only for android

`<a href={window.location.href} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer' download >`